# Get items to top and behind numbers?

Tags: css, position, alignment, absolute

[Image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iZw7.jpg) I'm trying to get the "arrow box" to be behind the 12% and spanning the entirety of the man div that wraps the 12% and arrows. Normally I would do this by setting the arrow box div to be absolute the top left set to 0. But when I do this it goes to top left 0 of the page? not the parent container. I have no clue why it does that. Hoping someone can help. As you can see in the pic its set to Relative in order to show you the two items in question.

```
<div class="data data-arrow good bg-dark-6/6">
            <div class="text-scale-max">12%</div>
            <div class="title-xs">Sales Increase</div>
            <vector-data-arrow :count="3" class="arrow-anim"></vector-data-arrow>
          </div>
```

```
.data-arrow {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
}
.arrow-wrap {
    @apply relative top-0 left-0 bg-white-0/6;
  }
  .arrow {
    @apply relative top-0 -mb-6 fill-white-0/6;

    &:last-child {
      @apply mb-0;
    }
  }
```

I've tried Absolute. And I have the container of those divs set to Relative as well.

Comment: Can you post your code please? Screen shots aren't much help tbh

Comment: according your text "But when I do this it goes to top left 0 of the page? not the parent container." and without anything else (code, html, css), I would say put position relative to parent container. Absolute without relative in parent is absolute of the page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: code provided. I am using tailwind css. Which is why I screen shotted the code rather than provide it. But i provided anyhow.